# Android web server connectivity?

Tags: android

I want to connect my moodle website to android such that the user login is done on android device via buttons made by GUI. And my moodle website should act as an server on my system. How to do this web server configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can request the data from the server the same way you do from the browser / desktop app, using HttpGet and HttpPost.

For authentication you should use `HttpPost` with `UrlEncodedFormEntity`:

```
[...]
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_SERVLET_URI);
List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", userName));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
httppost.setEntity(p_entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
[...]
```

Then you can parse your response in the appropriate manner (if it's xml than with `SAXParser` and `XMLReader`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create things like `WebServices` on your website's end, which will let your Android apps interact with the data of your website.